# Replace adjacent identical tokens that match a regex

Tags: python, regex

In a python application, I need to replace adjacent identical occurrences of whitespace separated tokens that match a regex, e.g. for a pattern such as "a\w\w"

```
"xyz abc abc zzq ak9 ak9 ak9 foo abc" --> "xyz abc*2 zzq ak9*3 foo bar abc"
```

EDIT

My example above didn't make it clear that tokens which don't match the regex should not be aggregated. A better example is

```
"xyz xyz abc abc zzq ak9 ak9 ak9 foo foo abc" 
--> "xyz xyz abc*2 zzq ak9*3 foo foo bar abc"
```

END EDIT

I have working code posted below, but it seems more complicated than it should be.

I'm not looking for a round of code golf, but I would be interested in a solution that's more readable using standard Python libraries with similar performance.

In my application, it's safe to assume that the input strings will be less than 10000 chars long and that any given string will contain only a handful, say < 10,  of the possible strings that match the pattern.

```
import re

def fm_pattern_factory(ptnstring):
    """
    Return a regex that matches two or more occurrences 
    of ptnstring separated by whitespace.
    >>> fm_pattern_factory('abc').match(' abc abc ') is None
    False
    >>> fm_pattern_factory('abc').match('abc') is None
    True
    """
    ptn = r"\s*({}(?:\s+{})+)\s*".format(ptnstring, ptnstring)
    return re.compile(ptn)

def fm_gather(target, ptnstring):
    """
    Replace adjacent occurences of ptnstring in target with
    ptnstring*N where n is the number occurrences.
    >>> fm_gather('xyz abc abc def abc', 'abc')
    'xyz abc*2 def abc'
    >>> fm_gather('xyz abc abc def abc abc abc qrs', 'abc')
    'xyz abc*2 def abc*3 qrs'
    """
    ptn = fm_pattern_factory(ptnstring)
    result = []
    index = 0
    for match in ptn.finditer(target):
        result.append(target[index:match.start()+1])
        repl = "{}*{}".format(ptnstring, match.group(1).count(ptnstring))
        result.append(repl)
        index = match.end() - 1

    result.append(target[index:])
    return "".join(result)

def fm_gather_all(target, ptn):
    """ 
    Apply fm_gather() to all distinct matches for ptn.
    >>> s = "x abc abc y abx abx z acq"
    >>> ptn = re.compile(r"a..")
    >>> fm_gather_all(s, ptn)
    'x abc*2 y abx*2 z acq'
    """
    ptns = set(ptn.findall(target))
    for p in ptns:
        target = fm_gather(target, p)
    return "".join(target)
```

Comment: do you need to use regexps for this?

Comment: @BorrajaX Yes, I believe so. The actual patterns to be matched are LilyPond full measure rests that have forms like 'R1*3/4' or 's1*13/16'. If you're curious, the project is on GitHub at https://github.com/Michael-F-Ellis/TransLily

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I was working on the answer before seeing you first comment. If this doesn't answer your question, let me know, and I'll remove it or will try to modify it accordingly.

For the simple input provided in the question (what in the code below is stored in the `my_string` variable), you could maybe try a different approach: Walk your input list and keep a "bucket" of `<matching_word, num_of_occurrences>`:

```
my_string="xyz abc abc zzq ak9 ak9 ak9 foo abc"
my_splitted_string=my_string.split(' ')
occurrences = []
print ("my_splitted_string is a %s now containing: %s"
       % (type(my_splitted_string), my_splitted_string))

current_bucket = [my_splitted_string[0], 1]
occurrences.append(current_bucket)
for i in range(1, len(my_splitted_string)):
    current_word = my_splitted_string[i]
    print "Does %s match %s?" % (current_word, current_bucket[0])
    if current_word == current_bucket[0]:
        current_bucket[1] += 1
        print "It does. Aggregating"
    else:
        current_bucket = [current_word, 1]
        occurrences.append(current_bucket)
        print "It doesn't. Creating a new 'bucket'"

print "Collected occurrences: %s" % occurrences
# Now re-collect:
re_collected_str=""
for occurrence in occurrences:
    if occurrence[1] > 1:
        re_collected_str += "%s*%d " % (occurrence[0], occurrence[1])
    else:
        re_collected_str += "%s " % (occurrence[0])
print "Compressed string: '%s'"
```

This outputs:

```
my_splitted_string is a <type 'list'> now containing: ['xyz', 'abc', 'abc', 'zzq', 'ak9', 'ak9', 'ak9', 'foo', 'abc']
Does abc match xyz?
It doesn't. Creating a new 'bucket'
Does abc match abc?
It does. Aggregating
Does zzq match abc?
It doesn't. Creating a new 'bucket'
Does ak9 match zzq?
It doesn't. Creating a new 'bucket'
Does ak9 match ak9?
It does. Aggregating
Does ak9 match ak9?
It does. Aggregating
Does foo match ak9?
It doesn't. Creating a new 'bucket'
Does abc match foo?
It doesn't. Creating a new 'bucket'
Collected occurrences: [['xyz', 1], ['abc', 2], ['zzq', 1], ['ak9', 3], ['foo', 1], ['abc', 1]]
Compressed string: 'xyz abc*2 zzq ak9*3 foo abc '
```

(beware of the final blank space)

Comment: I should have been clear in my question that the input strings may contains repeated tokens that should not be aggregated. I'll edit the question to make that more apparent. Thanks for taking a shot at it.

Comment: Your solution works quite well if the equality test is AND'ed with a test to see if the regex matches current_word. I'm upvoting it and will accept it in a day or so unless someone comes up with a solution that blows both of our approaches out of the water.

Comment: Something happened to the comment... I can't see the test **:-)**

Comment: Yeah, it is. You can always answer your own question and select your answer as the selected one. Maybe that'll help other readers in the future? Up to you **:-)**

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to be solid and has good performance in my application. Thanks to BorrajaX for an answer that pointed out benefits of not scanning the input string more often than absolutely necessary.

The function below also preserves newlines and whitespace in the output. I forgot to state that in my question, but it turns out to be desirable in my app which needs to produce some human-readable intermediate output.

```
def gather_token_sequences(masterptn, target):
    """
    Find all sequences in 'target' of two or more identical adjacent tokens
    that match 'masterptn'.  Count the number of tokens in each sequence.
    Return a new version of 'target' with each sequence replaced by one token
    suffixed with '*N' where N is the count of tokens in the sequence.
    Whitespace in the input is preserved (except where consumed within replaced
    sequences).

    >>> mptn = r'ab\w'
    >>> tgt = 'foo abc abc'
    >>> gather_token_sequences(mptn, tgt)
    'foo abc*2'

    >>> tgt = 'abc abc '
    >>> gather_token_sequences(mptn, tgt)
    'abc*2 '

    >>> tgt = '\\nabc\\nabc abc\\ndef\\nxyz abx\\nabx\\nxxx abc'
    >>> gather_token_sequences(mptn, tgt)
    '\\nabc*3\\ndef\\nxyz abx*2\\nxxx abc'
    """

    # Emulate python's strip() function except that the leading and trailing
    # whitespace are captured for final output. This guarantees that the
    # body of the remaining string will start and end with a token, which
    # slightly simplifies the subsequent matching loops.
    stripped = re.match(r'^(\s*)(\S.*\S)(\s*)$', target, flags=re.DOTALL)
    head, body, tail = stripped.groups()

    # Init the result list and loop variables.
    result = [head]
    i = 0
    token = None
    while i < len(body):
        ## try to match master pattern
        match = re.match(masterptn, body[i:])
        if match is None:
            ## Append char and advance.
            result += body[i]
            i += 1

        else:
            ## Start new token sequence
            token = match.group(0)
            esc = re.escape(token) # might have special chars in token
            ptn = r"((?:{}\s+)+{})".format(esc, esc)
            seq = re.match(ptn, body[i:])
            if seq is None: # token is not repeated.
                result.append(token)
                i += len(token)
            else:
                seqstring = seq.group(0)
                replacement = "{}*{}".format(token, seqstring.count(token))
                result.append(replacement)
                i += len(seq.group(0))

    result.append(tail)
    return ''.join(result)
```